# Why are these options correct for this state machine diagram question?

Tags: finite-state-machine

Considering the following state machine diagram, it is CORRECT to state that:

[image]

Select one or more:

a.
the Restart event will always be executed in the Halted state.

b.
After a Halt and Restart event and assuming no previous history is available the re-enter state will be State1

c.
Assuming the current state is State2 and Halt occurs and that there is no preferred entry state, the next state transition (after re-entry) will result in the current state to be State3.

d.
"Endop" is the final state.

e.
Only the Complete event can lead to the Completed state.

The correct options are B and C. I don't understand why. I know how state machine diagrams work but why is A not correct, there is a Restart arrow coming out of Halted so surely restart event will always be executed in halted state. For B, after a Halt and Restart it goes to the H, which is not State1. For C, I don't even understand what its asking. Could someone explain why these options are correct?

Answer (score 3):

A: "Restart" can happen at any time (state machine diagrams don't show when a specific event *occurs*, but instead when it's *handled*. I.e. "Restart" can happen anytime, but is only handled in the "Halted" state - in any other state it *can* occur, but is ignored. (I find it a bit misleading that the verb "execute" is used for an *event*, however.)

C: "H" is the "History connector": It stores the last state we were in before leaving "operating" and restores that state on re-entry. Thus, the next state after re-entry will be "State 3" ("State 2" will be restored and the machine will immediately transition to "State 3").

B: "Assuming no previous history is available" means we've never been in "Operating" before (otherwise, we had one after a "Halt" and "Restart"). With no history, we'll obviously end up in State 1 after re-entry.

Comment: Regarding C, wouldn't we expect a visible transition/arrow from H to State2?  Why is only the "no history" arrow explicitly shown?

Comment: @ErikEidt, H is not an actual state. It is a marker indicating that the composite state it is drawn in maintains a history and a transition to H should be interpreted as a transition to the sub-state that was active at the time we left the composite state. The explicit arrow is only to have a defined behavior if there is no last active sub-state.

Comment: @ErikEidt Exactly - In code, you simply retain the inner state of the FSM and go from there on re-entry without re-initializing the FSM.

Answer (score 0):

- not A: the Complete event can be executed in the Halted state.
- not D: "Completed" is the last final state, the proposed final state is merely that of the component.
- B is correct as you said: *assuming no previous history*.
- C is correct, (H) = history will preset with State 2 and come to State 3.

So the piece of knowledge one needs is that (H) is the *history* connector.
But B indeed gives a hint.